# Swift Combine: Using timer publisher in an observable object

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode11, combine

Before this question gets marked as duplicate of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57199922/create-a-timer-publisher-using-swift-combine), I am trying to understand how the publisher works as it behaves in a way I do not expect.

Using the same example as the answer from the question previously stated:

```
// Let's define the view model with my view...
import Combine
import SwiftUI

class TimerViewModel: ObservableObject {
  private let cancellable: AnyCancellable?

  let intervalPublisher = Timer.TimerPublisher(
                            interval: 1.0, 
                            runLoop: .main, 
                            mode: .default)

  init() {
    self.cancellable = timerPublisher.connect() as? AnyCancellable
  }

  deinit {
    self.cancellable?.cancel()
  }
}

struct Clock : View {
  @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: TimerViewModel
  @State private var currentTime: String = "Initial"


  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text(currentTime)
    }
    .onReceive(timer.intervalPublisher) { newTime in
      self.currentTime = String(describing: newTime)
    }
  }
}
```

At this stage, all I wanted to do is my view model to publish the value directly. I don't want to have to declare the view will be receiving these sorts of values.

Ideally, I want to turn my publisher into a published properly... I though that the following code would work:

```swift
// Let's define the view model with my view...
import Combine
import SwiftUI

class TimerViewModel: ObservableObject {
  private let cancellable: AnyCancellable?
  private let assignCancellable: AnyCancellable?

  let intervalPublisher = Timer.TimerPublisher(
                            interval: 1.0, 
                            runLoop: .main, 
                            mode: .default)
 @Published var tick: String = "0:0:0"

  init() {
    cancellable = intervalPublisher.connect() as? AnyCancellable

    assignCancellable = intervalPublisher
                              .map { new in String(describing: new) }
                              .assign(to: \TimerViewModel.tick, on: self)
  }

  deinit {
    cancellable?.cancel()
    assignCancellable?.cancel()
  }
}

struct Clock : View {
  @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: TimerViewModel
  @State private var currentTime: String = "Initial"


  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text(currentTime)
      Text(viewModel.tick) // why doesn't this work?
    }
    .onReceive(timer.intervalPublisher) { newTime in
      self.currentTime = String(describing: newTime)
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong for my `assign`?

Why isn't triggering?

*Edit: the environment object was set on the `SceneDelegate` once the Clock view was created. The code excluded is attached below:*

```swift
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).

        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let view = Clock().environmentObject(TimerViewModel())

        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

Comment: This already helped a different question today. Same basic issue in many ways - a `@Published` variable not updating. Received my fifth upvote on my answer (even though for some reason it wasn't accepted). Try it and see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57511826/change-to-published-var-in-environmentobject-not-reflected-immediately/57513103#57513103 basically it's two things: (1) There is *no* implied `objectWillChange` which Apple declared a few betas ago, and (2) Many SwiftUI views suddenly work when you explicitly use `objectWillSend`. Hope this helps - if so, it's not you.

Comment: Interesting... I thought the `@Published` was implementing the wrapper required to work (at least on this scenario). I have tested it with a lot of other ones, but this threw me off balance.

Comment: Just gave you a bit of positive karma for it.

Comment: I upvoted your question because I was about to ask the same exact thing. The weird thing is that using Timer.TimerPublisher it won't work, BUT if you use Timer.publish (as suggested by Michael here below) it works. Maybe it's a bug? Or maybe we are missing something here. I think this is a very interesting question about Combine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a bit different to your original but nothing important is changed I hope.

```swift
import Combine
import SwiftUI

class TimerViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private var assignCancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil

    @Published var tick: String = "0:0:0"

    init() {
        assignCancellable = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: .main, in: .default)
            .autoconnect()
            .map { String(describing: $0) }
            .assign(to: \TimerViewModel.tick, on: self)
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var currentTime: String = "Initial"
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = TimerViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(currentTime)
            Text(viewModel.tick) // why doesn't this work?
        }
        .onReceive(Timer.publish(every: 0.9, on: .main, in: .default).autoconnect(),
                perform: {
                    self.currentTime = String(describing: $0)
                }
        )
    }
}
```

I made viewModel an ObservedObject just to simplify the code.

The Timer.publish method along with autoconnect make Timer easier to use. I have found that using the same publisher with multiple subscribers causes problems as the first cancel kills the publisher.

I removed the deinit() as the cancel seems to be implicit for subscribers.

There was an interference between updates from onReceive and viewModel but changing the onReceive to 0.9 fixed that.

Finally I have discovered that the print() method in Combine is very useful for watching pipelines.

Comment: Your solution is a good workaround, but I think the main issue here is: why doesn't Timer.TimerPublisher work while Timer.publish does its job? Is there a bug in Combine beta or rodrigoelp (and me actually) is missing something?

Comment: When I first tried using Timer it gave me no end of trouble, the I read through the documentation, found the publish factory and I wondered why anybody used any other method, the same with autoconnect.

Comment: In some cases, you want to control when the stream of intervals starts to flow. Granted, you could restructure your function calls to make it more functional composition as opposed to procedural execution (which is what I just did).

I still don't understand why Timer.TimerPublisher doesn't work =( on this particular scenario.

Comment: So, Michael, after giving it a bit of a thought. I will mark your comment as an appropriate answer. It achieves in a better way what I need to do. Thanks!

Comment: Just so people know using assign on self creates a retain cycle

Answer (score 4):

First try `Text("Timer: \(date, style:.timer)")` which gives you a counting timer automatically. Also, consider the advantage of `Timer.publisher` that it is a struct that can be stored in `@State` so you don't even need `ObservableObject`.

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct Clock : View {
  @State private var timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in:.common).autoconnect()
  @State private var currentTime: String = "Initial"

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text(currentTime)
    }
    .onReceive(timer) { newTime in
      self.currentTime = String(describing: newTime)
    }
  }
}
```

The advantage to having the `Timer` as `@State` is if the Clock is no longer displayed for some reason then the timer stops and is discarded too.

If however, you did decide to use `ObservableObject` then you could simply do:

```
class MyTimer : ObservableObject {
    var objectWillChange = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in:.common).autoconnect()
}

struct Clock2: View {
    @StateObject var timer = MyTimer() // causes body to run every second
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, World! \(Date())")
        }
    }
}
```

And here is another way that gives a more accurate change to the date string, however I don't like this sample because the date formatting needs to be done in a `Text` inside body so that the label updates if the region settings change.

```
class MyTimer : ObservableObject {
    var timer : Timer? = nil
    @Published var timeString = ""

    init() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { timer in
            self.timeString = timer.fireDate.description
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var timer = MyTimer()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, World! \(timer.timeString)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"@EnvironmentObject" must set a model object on an ancestor view.

I didn't see this.

So, I did rewrite your code.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    let timer = TimerViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World")
            TimerView().environmentObject(timer)
        }
    }
}

struct TimerView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var timer: TimerViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Text(timer.time)
    }
}

class TimerViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var time = "init"

    private let innerTimer = Timer.TimerPublisher(interval: 1.0, runLoop: .main, mode: .default)
    private let cancellable: Cancellable
    private var anyCancellable: AnyCancellable?

    init() {
        cancellable = innerTimer.connect()
        anyCancellable = innerTimer
            .map({ $0.description })
            .assign(to: \TimerViewModel.time, on: self)
    }

    deinit {
        cancellable.cancel()
        anyCancellable?.cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @adf, my environment object was set at the `SceneDelegate` (I forgot to mention it as I thought it was obvious when using the `@EnvironmentObject`

Thanks for taking the effort to comment even though it is understandable the misunderstanding as I left it out. (editing the post to include it)

Comment: It's unnecessary to call cancel during deinit because the publisher auto calls cancel() when it is deinit.

Also, I'm not sure why you have two cancellable's. I guess it's so that you can have different things with each cancellable. The problem with this approach is that if either call cancel, then innerTimer will cancel and so both cancellable's will stop receiving values from the publisher. I would consider looking at `.share()` and `.multicast()`.